DevOps self-hosted pipeline fails Microsoft trusted signing with error SignTool failed with exit code1
We have several DevOps build agents running on separate servers (we run one agent per server). Recently we implemented Microsoft Trusted Signing in our build pipelines, and it has been working without errors except for one agent that consistently fails the sign task.
steps:
- task: VisualStudioClient.TrustedSigning.TrustedSigning.TrustedSigning@0
  displayName: 'Sign $(APP_NAME)'
  inputs:
    AzureTenantID: '$(armada_tenantid)'
    AzureClientID: '$(azdevopscodesign_clientid)'
    AzureClientSecret: '$(azdevopscodesign-secret)'
    AzureClientSendCertificateChain: false
    Endpoint: 'https://weu.codesigning.azure.net/'
    TrustedSigningAccountName: ***
    CertificateProfileName: ***
    FilesFolder: '$(ALOPS_COMPILE_ARTIFACT)'
    AppendSignature: false
    GenerateDigestXml: false
    SignDigest: false
    GeneratePageHashes: false
    SuppressPageHashes: false
    GeneratePkcs7: false
    CodeSigningAccountName: ***

This is a failed output
2024-10-08T10:20:59.0089335Z ##[section]Starting: Sign *** AS
2024-10-08T10:20:59.0117626Z ==============================================================================
2024-10-08T10:20:59.0118052Z Task         : Trusted Signing
2024-10-08T10:20:59.0118289Z Description  : This task enables users to sign their files with the Trusted Signing service.
2024-10-08T10:20:59.0118647Z Version      : 0.4.4
2024-10-08T10:20:59.0118873Z Author       : Microsoft
2024-10-08T10:20:59.0119088Z Help         : 
2024-10-08T10:20:59.0119293Z ==============================================================================
2024-10-08T10:21:01.7864295Z Checking for required dependencies.
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8143318Z    Build tools package installed: True
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8146084Z    Trusted signing package installed: True
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8149622Z    All required dependencies are installed.
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8193346Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8194761Z Creating metadata file: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TrustedSigning\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53\bin\x64\metadata.json
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8418803Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8420959Z Getting the list of files to be signed.
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8436565Z    No files list was provided.
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8460901Z    Listed files: 0
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8475466Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8477438Z    Getting files from folder: E:\agent\veslepiggen\_work\19\a\*** AS_25.0.202441.43139_APP.app
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8480203Z    Filter: 
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8828769Z    Filtered files: 1
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8835105Z        E:\agent\veslepiggen\_work\19\a\*** AS_25.0.202441.43139_APP.app
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8839437Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8841183Z    No catalog file was provided.
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8845320Z    Catalog files: 0
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8848308Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8849256Z Formatting the list of files to be signed.
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8926329Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:01.8927392Z Batching the list of files to be signed.
2024-10-08T10:21:01.9119780Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:01.9121247Z Signing file batch 1 of 1.
2024-10-08T10:21:01.9447442Z    Executing signtool.exe: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TrustedSigning\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.10.0.22621.3233\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe sign /v /debug /fd SHA256 /tr http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com /td SHA256 /dlib "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TrustedSigning\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53\bin\x64\Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.dll" /dmdf "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TrustedSigning\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53\bin\x64\metadata.json" "E:\agent\veslepiggen\_work\19\a\*** AS_25.0.202441.43139_APP.app"
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2670487Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2688449Z SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2689570Z SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: E:\agent\veslepiggen\_work\19\a\*** AS_25.0.202441.43139_APP.app
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2690147Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2690670Z Number of files successfully Signed: 0
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2691096Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2691578Z Number of warnings: 0
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2691812Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2692264Z Number of errors: 1
2024-10-08T10:21:02.2692504Z 
2024-10-08T10:21:02.7026700Z ##[error]SignTool failed with exit code 1
2024-10-08T10:21:02.7555089Z ##[section]Finishing: Sign *** AS

This is a successful output
2024-10-08T08:16:00.2393310Z ##[section]Starting: Sign *** AS
2024-10-08T08:16:00.2424913Z ==============================================================================
2024-10-08T08:16:00.2425385Z Task         : Trusted Signing
2024-10-08T08:16:00.2425648Z Description  : This task enables users to sign their files with the Trusted Signing service.
2024-10-08T08:16:00.2426058Z Version      : 0.4.4
2024-10-08T08:16:00.2426310Z Author       : Microsoft
2024-10-08T08:16:00.2426578Z Help         : 
2024-10-08T08:16:00.2426808Z ==============================================================================
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0168446Z Checking for required dependencies.
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0468792Z    Build tools package installed: True
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0475053Z    Trusted signing package installed: True
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0481270Z    All required dependencies are installed.
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0567392Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0568877Z Creating metadata file: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TrustedSigning\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53\bin\x64\metadata.json
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0844358Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0845931Z Getting the list of files to be signed.
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0895939Z    No files list was provided.
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0959908Z    Listed files: 0
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0987341Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0988676Z    Getting files from folder: E:\agent\gaustatoppen\_work\18\a\*** AS_25.0.202441.43126_APP.app
2024-10-08T08:16:02.0996027Z    Filter: 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1377151Z    Filtered files: 1
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1383445Z        E:\agent\gaustatoppen\_work\18\a\*** AS_25.0.202441.43126_APP.app
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1387654Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1388572Z    No catalog file was provided.
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1394047Z    Catalog files: 0
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1397338Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1398241Z Formatting the list of files to be signed.
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1488385Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1490088Z Batching the list of files to be signed.
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1683945Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.1685288Z Signing file batch 1 of 1.
2024-10-08T08:16:02.2015845Z    Executing signtool.exe: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TrustedSigning\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.10.0.22621.3233\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe sign /v /debug /fd SHA256 /tr http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com /td SHA256 /dlib "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TrustedSigning\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53\bin\x64\Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.dll" /dmdf "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TrustedSigning\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client\Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53\bin\x64\metadata.json" "E:\agent\gaustatoppen\_work\18\a\*** AS_25.0.202441.43126_APP.app"
2024-10-08T08:16:02.4462490Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.4463774Z Trusted Signing
2024-10-08T08:16:02.4464035Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.4629180Z Version: 1.0.53
2024-10-08T08:16:02.4629468Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5894386Z "Metadata": {
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5895195Z   "Endpoint": "https://weu.codesigning.azure.net/",
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5895900Z   "CodeSigningAccountName": "***",
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5896595Z   "CertificateProfileName": "***",
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5897190Z   "ExcludeCredentials": [
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5897750Z     "InteractiveBrowserCredential"
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5898277Z   ]
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5898677Z }
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5898885Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:02.5899363Z Submitting digest for signing...
2024-10-08T08:16:03.8592314Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:03.8602021Z OperationId f4027a74-1426-4f77-acb7-2e3ae2b6e5bf: InProgress
2024-10-08T08:16:03.9363527Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:03.9405067Z Signing completed with status 'Succeeded' in 1.3469139s
2024-10-08T08:16:03.9405505Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2230504Z Successfully signed: E:\agent\gaustatoppen\_work\18\a\*** AS_25.0.202441.43126_APP.app
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2231462Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2231670Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2247646Z Number of files successfully Signed: 1
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2248021Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2251968Z Number of warnings: 0
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2252866Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2254158Z Number of errors: 0
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2254453Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2489850Z 
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2491201Z Trusted Signing completed successfully
2024-10-08T08:16:04.2529976Z Trusted Signing completed successfully
2024-10-08T08:16:04.3168555Z ##[section]Finishing: Sign *** AS

As far as we can tell, there are only three requirements to the self-hosted server.

Windows 7+
Running Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Standard
PowerShell 5.1+
Running PSVersion 5.1.20348.2652
.NET runtime 6.0+
Running Microsoft .NET Runtime 8.0.4

The same build pipeline will succeed on one agent and consistently fail on the second agent.
Is there some key requirement we are missing on the server where the failing agent is running that explains why the trusted signing service does not recognize the *.app file, or what would be the obvious thing to check on our part? Since both agents are running the same pipeline, we assume that the cause of the error is either on the failing agent or the server where the failing agent is running, but we are dumbstruck as to what this "thing" is...

We finally figured it out. You need to register NavSip.dll in SysWOW64. This is done by creating a Business Central Docker container using BcContainerHelper in Powershell, and then running cmdlet Install-NAVSipCryptoProviderFromBcContainer. This will extract NavSip.dll from the container and install it on your local machine.
